# glimpse in asp.net mvc4 app not working while deploying to some servers

Tags: glimpse

I am using glimpse in an asp.net mvc4 application. 
It is working good locally and in my development server that I have deployed without any issue. But in another testing server I am getting the following error in glimpse.log. I am not sure why. I dont have access to both the servers and it is controlled by other teams.

```
2013-08-27 09:47:47.4020 | DEBUG | RuntimePolicy set to 'Off' by IRuntimePolicy of type 'Glimpse.Core.Policy.StatusCodePolicy' during RuntimeEvent 'EndRequest'. |
```

I can access the `url/glimpse.axd` and turn on glimpse from the test url, but after that nothing happens with glimpse. The below is my `web.config` for the test server with sensitive info removed.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
-->
<configuration>
<configSections>
<!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
<section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=4.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
<section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,log4net" />
<section name="glimpse" type="Glimpse.Core.Configuration.Section, Glimpse.Core" />
</configSections>   
<appSettings>
<add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0" />
<add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
<add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />

</appSettings>
<system.web>
<compilation targetFramework="4.0">
  <assemblies>
    <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
  </assemblies>
</compilation>
<authentication mode="Windows" />
<authorization>
  <deny users="?" />
</authorization>
<pages>
  <namespaces>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
  </namespaces>
</pages>
<!-- Glimpse: This can be commented in to add additional data to the Trace tab when using WebForms
    <trace writeToDiagnosticsTrace="true" enabled="true" pageOutput="false"/> -->
<httpModules>
  <add name="Glimpse" type="Glimpse.AspNet.HttpModule, Glimpse.AspNet" />
</httpModules>
<httpHandlers>
  <add path="glimpse.axd" verb="GET" type="Glimpse.AspNet.HttpHandler, Glimpse.AspNet"   />
</httpHandlers>
</system.web>
<system.webServer>
<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
  <add name="Glimpse" type="Glimpse.AspNet.HttpModule, Glimpse.AspNet"  preCondition="integratedMode" />
</modules>
<handlers>
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*."   verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule"  scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll"  preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
  <add name="Glimpse" path="glimpse.axd" verb="GET" type="Glimpse.AspNet.HttpHandler, Glimpse.AspNet" preCondition="integratedMode" />
</handlers>
</system.webServer>
<runtime>
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
<entityFramework>
<defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
  <parameters>
    <parameter value="v11.0" />
  </parameters>
  </defaultConnectionFactory>
 </entityFramework>
 <glimpse defaultRuntimePolicy="On" endpointBaseUri="~/Glimpse.axd">
 <!-- If you are having issues with Glimpse, please include this. It will help us figure  out whats going on. -->
 <logging level="Trace" />
 <inspectors> 
 <ignoredTypes> 
  <add type="Glimpse.Mvc.Inspector.DependencyInjectionInspector, Glimpse.Mvc4" /> 
</ignoredTypes> 
</inspectors>
<runtimePolicies>
<ignoredTypes>
    <add type="Glimpse.AspNet.Policy.LocalPolicy, Glimpse.AspNet"/>
</ignoredTypes>
</runtimePolicies>
</glimpse>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default Glimpse only kicks in for HTTP requests that result in a 200, 301 or 302 status code.

The line of the log file you included indicates that some other status code is being returned from that server. Perhaps you have an additional HTTP Module that is changing the status code configured on that server?